# Glassfish will not communicate with enterprise application

Tags: netbeans, glassfish

Hi guys I have a very frustrating and strange thing happening here, when I first ran my enterprise application everything was fine in netbeans and it deployed my project. When I went to run my application the 2nd time the project was being deployed for 2 hours and nothing ever happened. I know that it is not connecting to the glassfish server , but netbeans wont even let me change server either. I created a few other projects and I have the same problem, I tried re-installing it and it didnt help , if anyone knows the problem it would be much appreciated !

Comment: You need to get your hands dirty and debug this without using the IDE. Manually deploy your application, using asadmin and look through server.log for errors.

Comment: You still haven't really asked a question. Is there an error somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using jdk 1.7 so I changed to 1.6 and it worked :)